# How could you dynamically allocate a struct which contains an union?

Tags: c, memory, struct, union

I'm trying to understand the unions and I was trying to allocate dynamically a struct which contains an union, but when I try to print the result, I get only a very unexpected result, maybe it's a memory error. I don't know how to assign memory for the specific struct D or N, because the have different sizes.

```
typedef struct Workers{
        char Name[20];
        unsigned int age;
        unsigned int year, month , day;
        union
        {
                struct
                {
                        unsigned int year, month,day;
                } D;
                struct
                {
                        unsigned int free_days;
                        float earnings;
                } N;
        }Workers;
}Workers;
```

I can't understand how I need to allocate memory for this kind of structure. At the begin I allocate: `Workers *workers = malloc(sizeof(Workers))` and afterwards I realloc memory:  `( realloc(workers,sizeof(Workers*(nr_of_workers+1) ) )`.

`Workers[0]` is well read, but the next members got random values.

Comment: I do not understand what are you asking about. `I don't know how to assign memory for the specific struct D or N` Having `Workers *workers;` initialized properly do `workers->Workers.D.year = 1` or `workers->Workers.N.free_days = 5`

Comment: Perhaps you can show a specific but more complete example of what you tried.

Comment: Off-topic observation: you're using the identifier `Workers` for too many things. You've got the struct tag, the typedef, and the union identifier. As a minimum, I would give the union a different name.

Comment: When I allocate memory for the a new member, the new values will be random.Marius  |       20      |       2.31.2000       |       3.31.2002       |       ----
        Ion     |       158561641       |       774976302.839482377.808585596   |       959658030.842019638.926495799  |. This is my output, the first member of the struct is fine, but afterwards everything will be random.

Comment: It might be best to show what you're trying to do and what isn't working. You may be asking the wrong question and it would be easy to see what's going on with a [mcve].

Comment: Riffing on @user3386109's helpful note, it might be wise to make the structure tag and possibly the typedef *singular* - it holds just one `Worker` - leaving the plural `Workers` for some object or array that holds more than one.

Comment: @MrSaiba - After you reallocate your memory to increase the size, you have to intentionally initialize the extra part because - as you have seen - it's filled with random junk. This would be the case whether there's a union or not.

Comment: Post real code.  [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the `struct` contains a `union` doesn't change how you determine the size of the struct.  It's still `sizeof(Workers)`.

If you want to allocate space for an array of `n` workers, you want `sizeof(Workers) * n`.